# Unique extension of a linear functional given by a composition

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space with a dense linear subspace $\mathcal{D}$, and $(H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a separable Hilbert space.

Suppose that there is some $q\in H\setminus\{0\}$ and a linear operator $T : \mathcal{D}\rightarrow H$ (not necessarily bounded) such that

$$\tag{1}\phi(v) := \langle q, Tv\rangle \quad \text{ is continuous on $\mathcal{D}$.}$$

Clearly then, $\phi$ admits a unique continuous extension $\bar{\phi} : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

My question: Is the above sufficient to infer that there is a linear operator $S : E \rightarrow H$ such that

$$\tag{2}\bar{\phi}(v) = \langle q, Sv\rangle \quad \text{ for each $v\in E$}?$$

And is there anything that can be said about $S$ (boundedness, maybe uniqueness under some conditions on $q$ and $T$)? Any hints/references are welcome.